# docker remote API set IPAMconfig cannot unmarshal

Tags: javascript, docker, api, axios

I am trying to create a network with the docker API using the docker remote API, I have been trying almost everything but I keep getting this error: `json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field IPAM.IPAM.Options of type map[string]string`. I also got this error with a different type: `type network.IPAMConfig`.

Here are some logs, firstly my config object, then the error which includes the message, status and axios config.

```
the network config {
  "CheckDuplicate": false,
  "Driver": "bridge",
  "Name": "some-site5_com_net",
  "IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Config": [
      {
        "Subnet": "172.0.1.24/29",
        "IPRange": "172.0.1.24/29",
        "Gateway": "172.0.1.25"
      }
    ],
    "Options": []
  }
}
could not create network XHRerror: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field IPAM.IPAM.Options of type map[string]string
    at /home/node/app/server/functions/docker-network.js:47:43
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  status: 400,
  axiosConfig: '{\n' +
    '  "url": "/networks/create",\n' +
    '  "method": "post",\n' +
    '  "data": "{\\"CheckDuplicate\\":false,\\"Driver\\":\\"bridge\\",\\"Name\\":\\"some-site5_com_net\\",\\"IPAM\\":{\\"Driver\\":\\"default\\",\\"Config\\":[{\\"Subnet\\":\\"172.0.1.24/29\\",\\"IPRange\\":\\"172.0.1.24/29\\",\\"Gateway\\":\\"172.0.1.25\\"}],\\"Options\\":[]}}",\n' +
    '  "headers": {\n' +
    '    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",\n' +
    '    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",\n' +
    '    "User-Agent": "axios/0.20.0",\n' +
    '    "Content-Length": 198\n' +
    '  },\n' +
    '  "transformRequest": [\n' +
    '    null\n' +
    '  ],\n' +
    '  "transformResponse": [\n' +
    '    null\n' +
    '  ],\n' +
    '  "timeout": 0,\n' +
    '  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",\n' +
    '  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",\n' +
    '  "maxContentLength": -1,\n' +
    '  "maxBodyLength": -1,\n' +
    '  "socketPath": "/var/run/docker.sock"\n' +
    '}'
}
```

And the code

```js
console.log("the network config", JSON.stringify(networkConfig, null, 2))
const config = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "/networks/create",
  data: networkConfig,
  socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
}

axios(config)
.then(response => { return resolve(response.data.Id) })
.catch(err => {
  if (err.isAxiosError) return reject(new XHRerror(err.response.data.message, err.response.status, err.config))
  return reject(err)
})
```

Some relevant docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/NetworkCreate)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an empty array for the options field

```json
"Options": []
```

but it's actually a JSON object with arbitrary keys and string values

```json
"Options": {}
```

(Decoding the Go error message, "cannot unmarshal array" means you sent it an array value; `IPAM.IPAM.Options` is the Go name of the field, but you can see both `IPAM` and `Options` in your request; and the Go type `map[string]string` is a map or dictionary with string keys and string values, but no more structure than that, corresponding to a schemaless JSON object.)

Comment: oh my, I stumbled upon this after I pasted a example config.
It also says in the docs the options should be of type Array of Object
I decided I will do some trickery with JSON.toString filters and then parse it back to JSON, at least for tonight... Thanks for your help!